# Improving accuracy of multi-class text classifier

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, multi-class

I am trying to build a text classifier with 4 highly imbalanced classes. Data has around 4000 documents and highly sparse. I have used XGboost and few other algorithms.Highest accuracy is given by xgboost 70%. Please help or share links of articles that can help me improve the accuracy further.

Comment: Text classifier accuracy is usually not very high. Although it greatly depends on the feature matrix you have generated. May I ask what feature generation method you applied. in my experience, Tf-idf is a good one to start with progressing to word2vec and more complex approaches. Also for your unbalanced classes try balancing them using SMOTE.

Comment: It's almost impossible for me (or any of us) to know exactly what will improve your model, since that's very 1) dataset dependent and 2) model architecture dependent, or even 3) hyperparameter/initialization dependent. What I'd recommend is to do some error analysis on your results, e.g. via confusion matrix, looking at actual erroneous classifications and trying to understand why your model failed, and testing those hypotheses.